# FTM 2019 / Ancestry

Tags: naming-convention, family-tree-maker

Using FTM 2019 I'm gradually fixing all my locations using FTM standard terminology where possible.

I'm based in Glasgow, Scotland , UK, so most of my locations are here and generally not an issue.

However, trying to record a foreign location - Cairo, Egypt - the only option FTM gives is Al Qahirah, Al Qahirah, Egypt. I find this annoying as it implies that FTM will use the native language of the location. If the FTM user speaks only English and uses English for all worlwide locations, then this is a problem (for me anyway), suggesting Persian, Chinese, Russian etc. will all come up in the native language.

Is there any way the master database can be amended so that for English speaking users, English is the dominant language?

Comment: Couple of thoughts - how serious is the issue? Specifically, can you override the suggestion and use the English version? (As an aside, I am slightly baffled by the suggested name since "Egypt" is not, if I understand it, the Arabic name of the country). Secondly, it may be (and I know nothing of FTM) that the designers of FTM are relying on overrides because otherwise they would need to provide lots of alternative names in different languages.

Comment: Any place names can be overridden in FTM, but it defeats the questioner's purpose of using only "standard" place names (i.e., those that the FTM place-name authority recognizes and can locate in the place-name hierarchy).  I use standard FTM place names only when convenient, for multiple reasons, e.g., only contemporary place names (vs. historical place names) are recognized as standard.